# Get appropriate values from hexadecimal

Tags: c#, algorithm

Let's say I have to following table with values (1st row is the description)

> DESCRIPTION -> DECIMAL VALUE -> BIT NUMBER
>
> Option1 -> 1 -> 1
>
> Option2 -> 2 -> 2
>
> Option3 -> 4 -> 3
>
> Option4 -> 8 -> 4

```
OptionX -> 137438953472 -> 38
```

Now I have the following value: **0x7000000800000000**. How can I recognize, which options have been chosen based on that number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ulong v = 0x7000000800000000;
for( int i = 1; v != 0; ++i ) {
    if ((v & 1) != 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
    v >>= 1;
}
```

or use the `BitVector` class.

Comment: @ChrisF: Why couldn't C# just include the usual implicit conversions?

Comment: Perhaps the code to allow these had knock on effects? (Pure guess).

Comment: @ChrisF: I'm sure it's a misguided attempt to prevent `if (i = 5)`.  (Misguided because it doesn't catch `if (b = false)`)

Comment: and how to parse 0x7000000800000000 if it's string?

Comment: @niao: You can use `ulong.TryParse`, for example.  Since your string is hexadecimal, use the `NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Use the bitwise AND operator `&`, and possibly also the bit-shift operators, `<<` (shift left) and `>>` (shift right).

For example, option `n` has been chosen if `(options & (1 << (n - 1))) != 0` is true.

Comment: should I use some kind of loop?